# Angular authorization doesn't work due to CORS

Tags: angular, cors

I have angular project with login and authorization, the problem is that authorization doesn't work with the error message `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myserver/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

I've read several questions on this topic, and the main solution is to disable CORS in browser directly or with the help of extension. Is there any possibility to solve this problem another way, maybe with some code in angular?

Here is my login.ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '@services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-page',
  templateUrl: './login-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-page.component.css']
})
export class LoginPageComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    // redirect to home if already logged in
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [''],
      password: [''],
      first_name: [''],
      last_name: [''],
      phone: ['']
    });

    // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['/feed'] || '/';
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

  onLogin() {
    this.submitted = true;

    // stop here if form is invalid
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          this.error = error;
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
}
```

And auth.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { User } from '@models/user.model';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
  private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  public currentUser: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public get currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
  }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/api/auth`, { username, password })
      .pipe(map(user => {
        // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      }));
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
}
```

Maybe i can avoid this behaviour by adding header to my request? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, disabling CORS can be dangerous - forgot to enable it several times when browsing for coding tips. I got around the problem using a proxy.

1. Create proxy config file in your root folder of the project, eg. proxy.conf.json with contents:

`{
  "/api/v1": {
    "target": "https://www.example.com/",
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}`

Set secure as true if end point is HTTPS, false if HTTP. The above setup assumes your API is in /api/v1 at example.com. Adjust accordingly.

2. Modify your start command in package.json to something like this:

`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"`

The proxy only works on localhost. Compiled code will not call proxy.conf.json.